# In Java what is the relationship of an anonymous class to the type it is defined as?

Tags: java, nested, relationship, anonymous-types, anonymous-class

If the anonymous class is defined as the type of an interface then the anonymous class implements the interface, however if it's defined as the type of another class (as shown below) it doesn't seem to extend the class (as I was told it did).

```
public class AnonymousClassTest {

    // nested class
    private class NestedClass {
        String string = "Hello from nested class.";
    }

    // entry point
    public static void main (String args[]){
        AnonymousClassTest act = new AnonymousClassTest();
        act.performTest();
    }

    // performs the test
    private void performTest(){

        // anonymous class to test
        NestedClass anonymousClass = new NestedClass() {
            String string = "Hello from anonymous class.";
        };

        System.out.println(anonymousClass.string);

    }
}
```

Here, if the anonymous class extended the nested class then the out put would be "Hello from anonymous class.", however when run the output reads "Hello from nested class."

Comment: I think you are declaring a second field in your anonymous class. Try removing the String modifier. Making it string="hello from anonymous class." and making the string field non private.

Comment: This is true however I am trying to override the String in the anonymous class. To access the parent String should I not use `super.string`?

Comment: Ahh... I see now. I didn't realize that fields are not overrideable; only methods are. I was treating the String field like a method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fields are not overrideable. If a class declares a field named `string`, and a subclass also declares a field named `string`, then there are two separate fields named `string`. For example, this program:

```
class Parent {
    public String string = "parent";
    public int getInt() {
        return 1;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    public String string = "child"; // does not override Parent.string
    // overrides Parent.getInt():
    public int getInt() {
        return 2;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(final String... args) {
        Child child = new Child();
        System.out.println(child.string);            // prints "child"
        System.out.println(child.getInt());          // prints "2"
        Parent childAsParent = child;
        System.out.println(childAsParent.string);    // prints "parent" (no override)
        System.out.println(childAsParent.getInt());  // prints "2" (yes override)
    }
}
```

prints

```
child
2
parent
2
```

because `childAsParent` has type `Parent`, so refers to the field declared in `Parent`, even though the actual instance has runtime-type `Child`.

So if you modify your demonstration to use a method rather than a field, you will see the results you were expecting.

Comment: Ahhh I see, Thanks! I was treating the field like I would a method. So just to clarify the anonymous class does extend the type used to define it? However because it is defined as the parent type then accessing that field will access the parent's instance of it.

Comment: @JonathanWhite: Re: first question: Yes. Re: Second question: If I'm understanding you correctly, then -- not exactly. For example, `System.out.println(new NestedClass() { String string = "Hello from anonymous class."; }.string);` will print `"Hello from anonymous class."`, because it gets `string` from an expression whose type is the anonymous class. The reason that your `anonymousClass.string` is `"Hello from nested class."` is that your expression `anonymousClass` has type `NestedClass`. Do you see what I mean?